# Add new IP address to existing IPGroup in Azure using BICEP

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I want to update an existing IPGroup in Azure using BICEP. I want to append to the existing IP addresses already in the IPGroup.

I can easily overwrite the IPGroup, but this isn't what I'm looking for.

So far I have tried:

```
param newIPAddress string = '10.3.0.0/24'

    resource ipGroup 'Microsoft.Network/ipGroups@2020-08-01' = {
      name: ipGroups_all_spokes_subnets_name
      location: location
      properties: {
        ipAddresses: union(listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/ipGroups', ipGroups_all_spokes_subnets_name), '2020-08-01').properties.ipAddresses, [newIPAddress])
      }
    }
```

and

```
param newIPAddress string = '10.3.0.0/24'

resource existingIpGroup 'Microsoft.Network/ipGroups@2020-08-01' existing = {
  name: ipGroups_all_spokes_subnets_name
}

resource ipGroup 'Microsoft.Network/ipGroups@2020-08-01' = {
  name: ipGroups_all_spokes_subnets_name
  location: location
  dependsOn: [
    existingIpGroup
  ]
  properties: {
    ipAddresses: union(existingIpGroup.properties.ipAddresses, [newIPAddress])
  }
}
```

but I get an error when I submit it.

> Deployment template validation failed: 'Circular dependency detected
> on resource:
> '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/xxx'.
> Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-resources for usage details.'.
> (Code: InvalidTemplate)

How can I update an existing IPGroup, adding a single IP to the group in Azure?

Comment: As a workaround you can create a module for modifying the ip addresses. So obtain the existing ones and then pass them through a module in which you modify them. Not sure if there's a better way to do so.

Comment: @NotFound thanks. You directed me down the correct path.

Answer (score 3):

My approach at the start of the question was wrong. list/listkeys are not implemented in IPGroup.

I solved this by creating a new bicep file and referencing this as a module to get the existing IP Addresses. I then added the existing IP addresses to the new address.

**Get existing IP addresses module**

```
param ipGroupName string

resource existingIpGroup 'Microsoft.Network/ipGroups@2020-08-01' existing = {
  name: ipGroupName
}

output existingIpAddresses array = existingIpGroup.properties.ipAddresses
```

**main file**

```
module extractipgroup 'extractipgroup.bicep' = {
  name: 'extractipgroup'
  params: {
    ipGroupName:ipGroups_all_spokes_subnets_name
  }
}

var ipGroupAddresses = concat([
  '10.6.6.0/27'
], extractipgroup.outputs.existingIpAddresses)

resource ipGroup 'Microsoft.Network/ipGroups@2020-05-01' = {
  name: ipGroups_all_spokes_subnets_name
location: location
  properties: {
    ipAddresses: ipGroupAddresses
  }
}
```

Thanks to @notfound for directing me down the right path.